# How do I upload an audio file to a text channel

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to upload an mp3 file to a discord text channel when someone activates a command. Let's say someone says "country roads", it would upload an mp3 file of Country Roads. I don't know where to start. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the file locally to upload it (just like any other file):

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File('path/to/your/file.mp3'))
```

Comment: This worked. Although you need to do message.channel.send and not channel.send. Thanks!

Comment: oh sry I forgot that you need to get the messsage object first